# animation time base on width

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, algorithm

This is not a jquery problem But a general algorithm problem.

i have mentioned that my animation needs to work for 5 sec. On 1024 to 1600 monitor it woks fine. But on smaller monitor it's too fast. How do i slowdown based on screen width. i.e animation needs to calculated based on screen width,

say `i mention for 1024 width it needs to work for 7 sec`. Even if the screen decreases it should work for  7 sec.

Again on larger monitor since width is more again and time is less (7 sec) the animation is again fast so here again the time has to be increased.

Final effect from ratio of both needs to be same

Here is my code in case any one has a jquery solution

```
$("#plane").css({
    'margin-left'   : $(window).width() - 300,
    'position'  : 'absolute'
}).animate({
    "margin-left" : '35%'
}, 5000, 'linear', function(){
    $(this).animate({
        "opacity"       : 0,
        "margin-left"   : 0
    }, 2200, 'linear')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the desired time.

It sounds like you're describing an algorithm where if the window is less than 1024 px wide, then you want 7 seconds, but if greater than that, you want it to take longer.  So, let's say we scale the time linearly above 1024px so if it's 2048px wide then it would take 14 seconds.  That can be described with this calculation:

```
var animTime = 7000;
var width = $(window).width();
if (width > 1024) {
    animTime += Math.floor((width - 1024) / 1024) * 7000);
}
```

You could then split that time between your two pieces of the animation:

```
$("#plane").css({
    'margin-left'   : $(window).width() - 300,
    'position'  : 'absolute'
}).animate({
    "margin-left" : '35%'
}, Math.floor((5/7) * animTime), 'linear', function(){
    $(this).animate({
        "opacity"       : 0,
        "margin-left"   : 0
    }, Math.floor((2/7) * animTime), 'linear')
});
```

Comment: kind off i wnat it to work both more than and less than 1024 . I either case the animation scales up

Comment: @WebDeveloper - it makes no sense to me that you'd want to scale the time up for both smaller and larger screens, but somehow 1024 is a magic value that should remain unscaled.  I can't envision why that would make sense for human interaction.  But, if you wanted to do that, you can just add an `else` clause to my code and write whatever scaling algorithm you want for when it's less than 1024.  You haven't described what scaling algorithm you want so I can't really offer any code.

Comment: MY MAIN PROBLEM IS ABOVE/MY CODE is too fast on a iPad as the screen size is small

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that there will be any linear relationships in drawing-times across different machines, displays, and graphics cards that will allow you to easily compute how much time to use.

However, you can time how long an animation runs (*e.g.* via a callback).  Split off the first half-second or so of your animation.  On the target hardware have your code time how long that initial section takes to run, and adjust the limits for the rest of the animation accordingly.  For example, if the calibration section's nominal length is N and it takes time C to complete, and the nominal length of the main section is T, use time T' = T*R for the animation of the main section, where R is a speed ratio with initial value N/C.

Apply some sanity limits on R, and if you will be running several more animations, continue measuring completion times and updating the speed ratio accordingly.